# Is there a counter example to $x^2 \leq x^3$

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples

For what positive real numbers $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ does the inequality $x^2 \leq x^3$ hold?

I have tried but I cannot come up a counter example

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Pick some number $0<x<1$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

What about $x=1/2$?

In fact every positive number which is between zero and one can serve as a counter example.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some graphs.

[image: graphs]

I did this with $x^2$ in red and $x^3$ in blue... So see where the red graph is above the blue graph.